# GWT Compile crashes JVM (JDK 7 and JDK 8)

Tags: java, gwt, jvm

I've tried both JDK7 and JDK8 and when I compile our large GWT app, it always crash the JVM (JDK 7 or JDK8) on my Core i3 machine, but not with my AMD quad-core machine. So I am certain that the app would compile.

Now my issue is how to make sure `mvn gwt:compile` would not crash the JVM and the PC.

- Is there any command line arguments I can add to prevent this, for
  JDK 7 and JDK 8?
- Or gwt.xml setting

The problem is that my PC just hangs.

Comment: Which Java version exactly are you using? What's the message you're getting?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It isn't clear from your question what exactly exceptions you're getting with crashes. High level advice to get GWT Compiler work faster and stable is to allocate more memory for it. It should be something like `-Xmx1g` or `-Xmx2g` to prevent gwt compiler from throwing java.lang.OutOfMemoryError exception. Also remember that you should use x64 JDK to be able to allocate such a big amount of memory.